# Inner static object deserialization with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize json like this:

{
    "User.getToken": {
        "code": "200",
        "token": "0155649ce3ea4be98da9fc29376d8688",
        "user_name": "Andruw137",
        "user_avatar": "https://text.com/images/avatar/_/81546.png"
    }
}

with these lines of code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 

TokenRequest tokenRequest = mapper.readValue(String.valueOf(response), TokenRequest.class);
```

and this:

```
public class TokenRequest {

@JsonProperty("User.getToken")
public User user = new User();

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.User = user;
}

static class User {
    int code;
    String token;
    String user_name;
    String user_avatar;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }

    public String getUser_avatar() {
        return user_avatar;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }

    public void setUser_avatar(String user_avatar) {
        this.user_avatar = user_avatar;
    }
}
```

}

I've read through documentation but still getting error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class ru.amdm.amdm.authorization.TokenRequest] from Integral number (404); no single-int-arg constructor/factory method
                                                              at [Source: 404 .1; line: 1, column: 1]
```

I'd like to understand what that error message means and how to actually get such a json deserialized. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `static inner` s a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @EJP out of curiosity, how would you call an inner class that is declared static ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize a string `"code": "200"` into an integer. This will work if you remove the quotes: `"code": 200`.

Also, please add @JsonProperty("json_name") annotation to the object fields and name them using standard camel case:

`@JsonProperty("user_avatar") 
String userAvatar;`

Comment: Exactly what Jean-François mentions, but I believe it's better to fail early and enforce strong typing.